Initiate Azure DevOps Release Pipeline from Logic App and Retrieve Environment Variable Output from the pipeline
I'm working on automating a release pipeline using Azure DevOps and a Logic App. The goal is to initiate the release pipeline from the Logic App when an HTTP request is received and then to retrieve the output of an environment variable from the Azure DevOps pipeline to use it in the next stage of the Logic App.
Below is a summary of what I am trying to achieve and the issues I am encountering:
Steps:

Initiate Release Pipeline: Use a Logic App to start an Azure DevOps release pipeline.

Retrieve Environment Variable: Extract the output of a specific environment variable from the Azure DevOps pipeline.

Use Environment Variable in Logic App: Use the retrieved environment variable in the subsequent stage of the Logic App.


Logic App
I have encountered a couple of issues that I'm unable to resolve:

Infinite Loop with Delay: I added a delay to wait for a pipeline stage to complete successfully, but it results in an infinite loop.

JSON Parsing Issue: I tried to retrieve output environment variables of the pipeline using a parse JSON stage, but it is not functioning as expected.



What's Environment Variable you want to retrieve in the pipeline. Are you using a classic release pipeline or a yaml pipeline?

yes its a yaml pipeline, I want to get the Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Data;]Data" from the pipeline and use it in the logic app

The output variable set using logging command is only available to the next tasks during running time. You can't get it via the REST API, that's why you can't retrieve it in your Parse JSON action.
As a workaround, you can create a variable group in Azure DevOps and use it to store your target variable. See the detailed steps below.

Create a variable group in Azure DevOps and add a variable named Data.

Call REST API Variablegroups - Update in your pipeline and update the value of Data with your output variable's value.

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Data;]Test"'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $header = @{'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + "$(System.AccessToken)"}
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{Org Name}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{Variable Group Id}?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
      $body = @'
      {    
            "variables": {
                "Data": {
                    "value": "$(Data)"
                }
            },
            "name": "LogicApp",
            "variableGroupProjectReferences": [
                {
                    "projectReference": {
                        "id": "$(System.TeamProjectId)",
                        "name": "$(System.TeamProject)"
                    },
                    "name": "LogicApp",
                }
            ]
      }
      '@
      Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PUT -Headers $header -Body $body -ContentType application/json



Create a PAT with Variable Groups (Read) scope at least. Run the following PowerShell scripts locally to get base64string of the PAT.

$token = "{Your PAT}"
$newtoken = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
Write-Host $newtoken


Create a parameter in your Logic app and add the newtoken you get.


Add a HTTP action after Delay action and call REST API Variablegroups - Get to get the value of the variable.

URI: https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{VariableGroupId}?api-version=7.1-preview.2
Method: GET
Add a Header: "Authorization" : "Basic @{parameters('PAT')}"



Then you can see the variable in the response body of HTTP action, and you can retrieve the variable and use it in the next actions.




Thank you for the solution, instead of delay, can we add an HTTP request or response so that we know whether the build is successful or not

We can use REST API Builds - Get to check the result of the build. But if you don't use delay, you need to ensure that only when the result of the build is succeeded the next action consuming variable can run.

Below design worked for me:

then:

then:

Here I have taken Result in Compose to get the result of build pipeline, take it and then use Parse Json as you will get to know what is the type of output/result it is giving and then use respective schema according to it.
Output:


The issue is not with design as the design worked for me.
